# Turning a string into an int problems

Tags: c++, string, int, ascii

So I have managed to convert the string into an int. However, in code #1, when I try to assign it to the first slot in the array and print it out, it prints '<'. Why is it doing this? I know it has something to do with ascii characters. Code #2 prints out the int 60 which is what I want.

```
atoi(menuAttributes[c].c_str()) = 20;
    quantity[d] = 3;
    string price[14];


    #1
    price[0] = atoi(menuAttributes[c].c_str()) * quantity[d];
    cout << price[0] << endl;


    #2
    cout << atoi(menuAttributes[c].c_str()) * quantity[d] << endl;
```

Pretty much, I want price[0] to equal the int 60, not the char '<'. Thanks!

EDIT: Solved, thanks for everyones help. Noob here, apologies!

Comment: Missing semicola (`;`) after statements?

Comment: Apologies I'm new to this  but yes I am aware of that, thank you! But thats not whats causing the problem. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `atoi(menuAttributes[c].c_str()) = 20;` <-- what on earth is that supposed to achieve?

Comment: `price[0]` is a `std::string`. `atoi(menuAttributes[c].c_str()) * quantity[d]` is *not* a string. Doesn't the compiler complain about that assignment?

Comment: You are assigning a number to a string which isn't correct. The price array must be a numeric type array (int, float, ...) to have the value.

Answer (score 1):

it's because of your `price` definition:

```
string price[14];
```

- you have defined it as an array of 14 strings, and attempting to assign to the first string in the array (`price[0]`) a numerical value (which is bogus from string's point of view).

Once you define your price as `int price[14]`, then you'll get what you expect

Comment: Thank you, very dumb on my behalf!

Comment: Not at all, even pros make mistakes like that (the only difference they don't rush to publish it on stackoverflow ))))

Answer (score 0):

`price` needs to be defined as an integer array. When you try to store the integer value 60 in `price`, it's implicitly converted to `(char)60`, which is `<` on the ASCII table.